# What are all the "hidden" schema types from A-Frame?

Tags: javascript, schema, mozilla, aframe

I've been checking the [property types](https://aframe.io/docs/0.6.0/core/component.html#property-types) and some Github code (which I've completely forgotten where it is). The latter has shown different properties for the schema such as a "min" and "max" for numbers; a list of options for the string. I find them to be extremely helpful on defining certain characteristics.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to spot them in the documentation. Where can I get a list that showcases all these "hidden" types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are for the A-Frame Inspector to populate sliders and dropdowns. Here are all of them:

min (number)
max (number)
oneOf (dropdown)

Comment: Oh I see! So they don't have any repercussion with the way that the user interacts with it besides the inspector!!!